# String for C# from C++ COM

Tags: c#, c++, string, com

I have a C++ DLL and some functions return Unicode null-terminated strings:

```
void SomeFunc(wchar_t* StrBuf)
```

The caller must allocate StrBuf - string can be up to 256 characters.
This DLL also exposes a COM object to use this DLL from C# via COM. Definition in IDL:

```
[id(1), helpstring("bla")]
HRESULT SomeFunc([in,out] BSTR* TextStr, [out,retval] LONG* RetValue);
```

Currently the C# code looks like this:

```
string val = new string('\0', 256); // Allocate memory
MyComObj.SomeFunc(ref val); // Get string
val = val.Substring(0, val.IndexOf('\0')); // Convert from null-terminated string
```

Is there a way to define such a COM function so it can be used from C# easier? Right now it looks ugly and takes three lines to call the function or five lines if a function has two string parameters.

Comment: Look at com interop http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645736(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: This function is badly broken, it violates the Automation contract.  Your code is now mutating a string, strings are immutable in .NET.  It works by accident but there's plenty of room for destroying the integrity of the managed heap.  You will have to fix the function.

Comment: Ok, this solution is bad, but you did not suggest any better approach. "com interop" articles are not useful, they don't describe how to handle strings

Comment: Finally I found how to return string from C++ COM to C#:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1300122/marshalling-bstrs-from-c-to-c-sharp-with-com-interop

Comment: If you have a solution, please create and answer to your own question and mark it as the answer, so it's closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. In C++ I use this code in the COM wrapper:

```
STDMETHODIMP MyClassClass::SomeFunc(BSTR* OptionValue, LONG* RetValue)
{
    *RetValue = 0;
    UNICODECHAR txt[MAXSTATSTRLEN];

    //... Copy text to txt variable
    *OptionValue = W2BSTR(txt);
    return S_OK;
}
```

IDL:

```
[id(1), helpstring("")] HRESULT SomeFunc([out] BSTR* OptionValue, [out,retval] LONG* RetValue);
```

In C# it can now be called easily:

```
string val;
MyComObj.SomeFunc(out val);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have this exposed as a COM object, just use visual studio to add a reference to your object. It will automatically generate an assembly for you (I believe they call this a COM callable wrapper).

This will expose your COM objects methods to .NET and works unless you start trying to pass across some custom structures.

Here are some resources for you:

[COM Callable Wrapper](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f07c8z1c.aspx)

[COM Interop Part 1: C# Client Tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645736%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Comment: COM Callable wrapper is a runtime entity which serves as a proxy for the COM side, when managed side is acting like a **server**. For the OP's situation (.NET is the client), this proxy object is called [Runtime callable wrapper](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8bwh56xe.aspx), but this is also mostly irrelevant for the managed caller. Although VS helps with creating these managed signatures, it is still caller's responsibility to prevent memory leaks when needed by taking care of allocation and deallocation as necessary. And with `[In,Out]BSTR*`, VS doesn't help much.

Comment: In C# project I already use "add reference" to include my COM C++ object. Yes it creates an assembly. My question contains C# code that uses it. But it does not handle any string conversion. I just look for a correct way to work with IN/OUT string parameters in COM functions from C#.

Answer (score 0):

If the memory for the string in the client allocates and fills it to the COM server, you must use a StringBuilder:

```
// IDL code
HRESULT GetStr(/*[out]*/ LPSTR pStr);

// Interop
void GetStr(/*[out]*/ [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] StringBuilder pStr);

// C# code
var str = new StringBuilder(256);
MyComObj.GetStr(a);
```

Then the StringBuilder will be empty or filled with characters.